# How do I change an HTML table cell value by a dynamically added button in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var insert = document.getElementById('insertitem');
insert.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('insertfirsttable'),
    itemType = prompt("Enter the Item type"),
    filling1 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    filling2 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    filling3 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    stock = prompt("Enter the amount in stock"),
    minimum_Stock = prompt("Enter the stock minimum");

  for (var r = 0; r < 1; r += 1) {
    var x = document.getElementById('insertfirsttable').insertRow(r);
    for (var c = 0; c < 10; c += 1) {
      var y = x.insertCell(c);
    }

    table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML = itemType;
    table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML = filling1;
    table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML = filling2;
    table.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML = filling3;
    table.rows[r].cells[4].innerHTML = stock;
    table.rows[r].cells[5].innerHTML = minimum_Stock;
    table.rows[r].cells[9].style.width = "100px";
    var CreateBtn = document.createElement("button");
    CreateBtn.innerHTML = "sell";
    CreateBtn.id = "sellbtn";
    CreateBtn.style.width = "100px";
    CreateBtn.style.height = "25px";
    CreateBtn.style.cursor = "pointer";
    CreateBtn.style.fontSize = "18px";
    table.rows[r].cells[9].appendChild(CreateBtn);
    var sellBtn = document.getElementById("sellbtn");
    CreateBtn.onclick = function Sell() {
      var sell = prompt("Enter the amount of stock you're selling");
      for (var a = 0; a < table.length; a += 1) {
        for (var b = 0; b < table.cells.length; b += 1) {

        }
      }
      table.rows[a].cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(table.rows[a].cells[4].innerHTML) - sell;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  font-size: 20px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  padding: 1px;
}
#firsttablediv {
  width: 100%;
}
#firsttable {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
#insertitem {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#insertfirsttable > tr {
  background-color: #31B404;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="firsttablediv">
    <table id="firsttable" border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>Item Type</th>
        <th colspan="3">Filling</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Stock Minimum</th>
        <th>Closing Inventory</th>
        <th>Sell</th>
        <th>Last Month Inventory</th>
        <th colspan="2">
          <button id="insertitem">New Item</button>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="insertfirsttable">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I press on the sell button (which is dynamically added by JavaScript to each row when an item is added)

I want it to ask me about the amount I want to sell of that item and then when I enter the amount it should subtract the stock amount from the amount I want to sell (the one entered previously) and then update the stock amount in the cell of that item's row to the new number.

It's pretty simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
table.rows[a].cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(table.rows[a].cells[4].innerHTML) - sell;
```

to this line:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[4].innerHTML) - sell;
```

To do it like you're trying, you would have to use a closure. This way, when you click a button, it adjusts the value of the button's parent's (td) parent (tr) cell 4.

Comment: Thank you so much works like a charm. I kinnda felt i had to do something with this.parentNode.parentNode but didn't know what exactly haha :D and btw since you called the parentNode twice then it's targeting the <tr> am i right? Thanks again

Comment: You're very welcome. **"...and btw since you called the parentNode twice then it's targeting the <tr> am i right?"**
Precisely. This way, the button's position determines the row being edited.

Comment: Ok perfect just one more question if you can help me with it. I now want the amount sold to be put in the sell cell(cell[6]) of that row and to keep adding itself whenever i sell some more it's very similar to what you've done i think but i just tried and i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowCount =0; // add a counter  for your row
var insert = document.getElementById('insertitem');
insert.addEventListener('click', function() {
    rowCount++; // increase row counter
  var table = document.getElementById('insertfirsttable'),
    itemType = prompt("Enter the Item type"),
    filling1 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    filling2 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    filling3 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    stock = prompt("Enter the amount in stock"),
    minimum_Stock = prompt("Enter the stock minimum");

  for (var r = 0; r < 1; r += 1) {
    var x = document.getElementById('insertfirsttable').insertRow(r);
    for (var c = 0; c < 10; c += 1) {
      var y = x.insertCell(c);
    }

    table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML = itemType;
    table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML = filling1;
    table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML = filling2;
    table.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML = filling3;
    table.rows[r].cells[4].innerHTML = stock;
    table.rows[r].cells[4].id = "stock_"+rowCount; // add an id to your cell
    table.rows[r].cells[5].innerHTML = minimum_Stock;
    table.rows[r].cells[7].id = "sell_"+rowCount;
    table.rows[r].cells[7].innerHTML = "0";
    table.rows[r].cells[9].style.width = "100px";
    var CreateBtn = document.createElement("button");
    CreateBtn.innerHTML = "sell";
    CreateBtn.id = "sellbtn";
    CreateBtn.title = rowCount; // add title to your button to have the row counter
    CreateBtn.style.width = "100px";
    CreateBtn.style.height = "25px";
    CreateBtn.style.cursor = "pointer";
    CreateBtn.style.fontSize = "18px";
    table.rows[r].cells[9].appendChild(CreateBtn);
    var sellBtn = document.getElementById("sellbtn");
    CreateBtn.onclick = function Sell() {
        var sell = prompt("Enter the amount of stock you're selling");
        stock_cell = document.getElementById("stock_"+this.title); // find the stock cell with row counter
        sell_cell = document.getElementById("sell_"+this.title);

        stock_item = parseInt(stock_cell.innerHTML); // get the current value
        sell_item = parseInt(sell_cell.innerHTML);

        stock_cell.innerHTML = stock_item - parseInt(sell); // increase sell item from stock
        sell_cell.innerHTML = sell_item + parseInt(sell);

    }
  }
```

Comment: You put an empty function in the onclick

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpmdvj73/1/))

```js
var insert = document.getElementById('insertitem');
insert.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('insertfirsttable'),
    itemType = prompt("Enter the Item type"),
    filling1 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    filling2 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    filling3 = prompt("Enter the filling"),
    stock = prompt("Enter the amount in stock"),
    minimum_Stock = prompt("Enter the stock minimum");

  for (var r = 0; r < 1; r += 1) {
    var x = document.getElementById('insertfirsttable').insertRow(r);
    for (var c = 0; c < 10; c += 1) {
      var y = x.insertCell(c);
    }

    table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML = itemType;
    table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML = filling1;
    table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML = filling2;
    table.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML = filling3;
    table.rows[r].cells[4].innerHTML = stock;
    table.rows[r].cells[5].innerHTML = minimum_Stock;
    table.rows[r].cells[9].style.width = "100px";
    var CreateBtn = document.createElement("button");
    CreateBtn.innerHTML = "sell";
    CreateBtn.id = "sellbtn";
    CreateBtn.style.width = "100px";
    CreateBtn.style.height = "25px";
    CreateBtn.style.cursor = "pointer";
    CreateBtn.style.fontSize = "18px";
    table.rows[r].cells[9].appendChild(CreateBtn);
    var sellBtn = document.getElementById("sellbtn");
    CreateBtn.onclick = function Sell() {
      var sell = prompt("Enter the amount of stock you're selling");
      for (var a = 0; a < table.length; a += 1) {
        for (var b = 0; b < table.cells.length; b += 1) {

        }
      }
      table.rows[a].cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(table.rows[a].cells[4].innerHTML) - sell;
      table.rows[a].cells[7].innerHTML = (parseInt(table.rows[a].cells[7].innerHTML)) ? parseInt(table.rows[a].cells[7].innerHTML) + parseInt(sell) : sell;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  font-size: 20px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  padding: 1px;
}
#firsttablediv {
  width: 100%;
}
#firsttable {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
#insertitem {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#insertfirsttable > tr {
  background-color: #31B404;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="firsttablediv">
    <table id="firsttable" border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>Item Type</th>
        <th colspan="3">Filling</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Stock Minimum</th>
        <th>Closing Inventory</th>
        <th>Sell</th>
        <th>Last Month Inventory</th>
        <th colspan="2">
          <button id="insertitem">New Item</button>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="insertfirsttable">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```